# Java - Converting escaped string to chars

Tags: java, string, unicode, char

Edit:  False!  The code below works, in my instance the string is being read as "\n", which gives me 2 characters rather than one. I am silly.

I'm trying to convert an isolated single character from a string to a char.  I'm having trouble getting escaped characters to convert to a single char, as it treats the \ as a separate character.

```
String str = "\n"; 
char charVal = str.charAt(0); // Gives charVal as \
```

Is there a function which interprets the escaped sequence as a single char instead of separate ones?

I'm trying to do this without the Apache commons package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to updated question:** Your results are getting confused somehow. `str` has exactly one character, so `charVal` will be that character, the line feed. Check the output, and if it still isn't what you expect, give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating your problem.

**Original answer:** `temp` is not `str`, and `str.charAt(0)` would definitely not give `\` as the result. `str` is a one-character string, so you'd only ever get that one character out, which is a line feed. Likely, you have something further up in your code like:

```
String temp = "\\n";
```

In that case, you have a two-character string, where the first is a backslash.

Comment: You need to check the output again, then, because what you've written above isn't correct. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct.  The input is coming from a file but the reader is adding extra \'s.  Simplifying the string does fix the issue.

Comment: On a related note- it does indeed seem I have "\\n" as you said. str.replace("\\n","\n") seems to make it behave well.  Is there a more general form to insert an escape?  Obviously str.replace("\\","\") will not work.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. It sounds like something you might want to explain in a new SO question.

Answer (score 2):

Cant reproduce

```
    String str = "\n";
    char charVal = str.charAt(0);

    System.out.println(charVal);
```

gives newline

Comment: @RyanStewart yes just noticed thanx

Comment: Thank you!  Editing original to reflect my silliness.